Isn't the header included in the chunked http response?
I heard when we send http response with Transfer-encoding: chunked header, http message is sent as chunk separately.
If we have http response message like below,
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

7\r\n
Mozilla\r\n
11\r\n
Developer Network\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n

So Does this message sent separately ("7\r\nMozilla\r\n" and "11\r\nDeveloper Network\r\n") without http header? Then How client identify it as http message? What if there are more than two Transfer-encoding: chunked http message sent to a one client? How can a client distinguish what chunk is part of particular message?
I have no idea in what format is this message sent finally.
